# navigator.serviceWorker is never ready

Tags: service-worker

I registered a service worker successfully, but then the code

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {
    // Do we already have a push message subscription?
    ....
```

hangs -- the function is never called. Why?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The problem was that the service-worker.js file was stored in an `assets` sub-directory.

Don't do that: store the service-worker.js in the `root of your app` (or higher). That way your app can access the service-worker.

See [HTML5Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/) --

> One subtlety with the register method is the **location of the service worker file.** You'll notice in this case that the service worker file is at the root of the domain. This means that the service worker's scope will be the entire origin. In other words, this service worker will receive fetch events for everything on this domain. If we register the service worker file at /example/sw.js, then the service worker would only see fetch events for pages whose URL starts with /example/ (i.e. /example/page1/, /example/page2/).

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My service worker is registered at https://test.example.com/background-worker.js and my Javascript code navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) is running on https://test.example.com/blog/

It is getting successfully registered but this function is never called. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: See newly added info in the answer

Comment: This answer really help me with my same problem.

Comment: was banging my head around for hours until i saw this :D

Comment: For me it was super lame: had to close the tab of the browser (`Chrome`) and open it again. Clearing the cache storage, the browser cache and unregistering the service worker had none effect.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been beating around the bush for two days, and all that I had to do was move sw.js from scripts to root...

Comment: Thank you man, you saved my day, it's strange that chrome require to have sw on root level of site.

Comment: Is it possible that redirects won't work either? If I go to my project page directly, then the serviceworker ready function will be called (promise resolves). If I go to my project page with a redirect (google login), then this ready function will not be called. Workarounds?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was struggling to figure out what was going wrong

Answer (score 9):

Like said in the accepted answer, the problem is, indeed, probably because your service worker JS file is in a different path than your current page.

By default, the scope of the service worker is the path to its JS file. If your JS file is reachable at `http://www.example.com/assets/js/service-worker.js`, your service worker will only work/"be ready" for URL starting with `/assets/js/`.

But, you can change the scope of the service worker. First, you need to register if using the `scope` option:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('http://www.example.com/assets/js/service-worker.js', {
    scope: '/',
});
```

If you do, just this, you will get errors in the Chrome console:

> The path of the provided scope ('/') is not under the max scope
>   allowed ('/assets/js/'). Adjust the scope, move the Service Worker
>   script, or use the Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header to allow the
>   scope.
>
> /admin/#/builder:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to
>   register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://www.example.com/') with
>   script
>
> ('http://www.example.com/assets/js/service-worker.js'): The path of
>   the provided scope ('/') is not under the max scope allowed
>   ('/assets/js/'). Adjust the scope, move the Service Worker script, or
>   use the Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header to allow the scope.

You then need to create an `.htacess` file at the root of your website with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <Files ~ "service-worker\.js">
        Header set Service-Worker-Allowed: /
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, but putting service worker and installing script in the same directory didn't solve this. For me the solution was to add a "/" to the end of the url.
So i had:

`http://localhost:9105/controller/main.js` - installing script

`http://localhost:9105/controller/sw.js` - service worker

`http://localhost:9105/controller/index.html` - page

And when the url in the browser was `http://localhost:9105/controller` service worker have never been ready, but when url is `http://localhost:9105/controller/` it works fine.

I used code below to control this

```
if (!window.location.href.endsWith('/')) {
    window.location.assign(window.location.href + '/')
  }
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense and is consistent with what was said in other answers.
http://localhost:9105/controller refers to controller in the  http://localhost:9105/ scope  where as  http://localhost:9105/controller/ is the location where is your sw.js is in a http://localhost:9105/controller/ scope (which is more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Add **service-worker.js** file to your **project root directory**

You can download **service-worker.js** file from [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker)

And use below code to register service worker.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   navigator.serviceWorker
     .register('./service-worker.js', { scope: './' })
       .then(function (registration) {
          console.log("Service Worker Registered");
    })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Service Worker Failed to Register", err);
     })

 }
```

Comment: Link broken, if you can update it will be nice