# Service Worker controllerchange never fires

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I want to send a message to a service worker every time the page loads.

The first time the page loads it calls register() and then listens for the "controllerchange" event on navigator.serviceWorker but this never fires.

How do I know when I can start postMessaging a service worker?

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(swURL).then(function(){
    var sw;

    if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
        sw = navigator.serviceWorker.controller;
        sw.postMessage('ping');
        return;
    }

    function onchange(){
        sw = navigator.serviceWorker.controller;
        sw.postMessage('ping');
        navigator.serviceWorker.removeEventListener('controllerchange', onchange);
    }

    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', onchange);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // registration failed :(
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I know when I can start postMessaging a service worker?

Just focusing on that bit: I'd recommend the following approach, which makes use of the [`navigator.serviceWorker.ready`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/ready) promise:

```
// navigator.serviceWorker.ready can be used from anywhere in your
// page's JavaScript, at any time.
// It will wait until there's an active service worker, 
// and then resolve with the service worker registration
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
  registration.active.postMessage('ping');
});
```

If you do want to get to the bottom of why your `controllerchange` event listener isn't firing, my guess would be that you're not using [`clients.claim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim) in your service worker's `activate` event, which means the newly-activated service worker won't take control of the current page.

Comment: For me `navigator.serviceWorker.oncontrollerchange` and `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` never fired untill I cleaned the Storage, closed the tab and opened it again. Just relaoding the page didn't help. Followed the suggestion from this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874068/navigator-serviceworker-is-never-ready#comment70763814_29874095

Comment: Interesting thing I noticed though. If you make requests immediately when `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` resolves SW won't catch these requests, but if you do it using `navigator.serviceWorker.oncontrollerchange` SW will catch those. Checked by appending in `body` script tags.

Comment: I am using `clients`.claim but still not working, I have tried with your method but still nothing. Funny things is that it was working till yesterday...

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not firing is because you are registering the `controllerchange` event *after* the Service Worker has already installed/activated. So this event will fire for *new* Service Workers, e.g. ones that use `skipWaiting()`. But not for the initial Service Worker.

Use `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` promise which resolves as soon as there is an active Service Worker detected, no matter when it was installed/activated.