# Passing data to service worker js on initialization

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Is it possible to pass data, or use a global defined variable in the main thread, to a service worker?

For example, I need to initialize a firebase messaging lib and I want to pass a messagingSenderId parameter (without making additional requests)

I couldn't find a way to do this as I see that the register method does not have useful options:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register

and the no object defined in the "window" is not accessible in service worker "self" (the accepted answer here does not work: [Global variable in Web worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219775/global-variable-in-web-worker) - maybe I am not accessing the variables correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like [Service Worker postMessage](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/post-message/)!
I hope this helps

Comment: It seems it is the only way, but it can be tricky to post a message right after registration. This helped me fixing some issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161452/service-worker-controllerchange-never-fires

Answer (score 1):

The service worker can see its own URL (without fragment) via the `location` object so you can pass some query string values and have it use them in its initialization. And you can use `new URLSearchParams(location.search)` to parse query string values in a standard way instead of custom string parsing of `location.href`.