# JavaScript Notifications and Service Worker API: Why is the serviceWorker.ready promise after registration?

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, service-worker

I tried to create a simple notification function for my web app using JavaScript. To do this, I tried to register a service worker which will send the notifications to support notification API stuff like `action`.

Here is my code:

```js
 1 navigator.serviceWorker.register('/scripts/dummy.js');
 2 
 3 function notify(title, data) {
 4   console.log('function call');
 5   if (Notification.permission == 'granted' && defaultStatus != 'dnd') {
 6     console.log('permission and not dnd');
 7     navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
 8       console.log('ready, send notification);
 9       registration.showNotification(title, data);
10     });
11   }
12 }
```

The Problem is at `navigator.serviceWorker.ready`
Chrome developer console says [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77JSZ.png). Do I need to put something into `dummy.js`? (It is currently empty, but I think it worked before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. The reason why it didn't work was because I moved the `dummy.js` from the current directory into a subdirectory.

Here is the error I got from Chrome after adding the option `{ scope: '/' }` to the `serviceWorker.register` function:

```
The path of the provided scope ('/') is not under the max scope allowed ('/scripts/user/'). Adjust the scope, move the Service Worker script, or use the Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header to allow the scope.
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://mydomain/') with script ('https://mydomain/scripts/user/user_worker.js'): The path of the provided scope ('/') is not under the max scope allowed ('/scripts/user/'). Adjust the scope, move the Service Worker script, or use the Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header to allow the scope.
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29874095/13505160) answer on stackoverflow for more information