# Set up Django push notification for web only

Tags: django, django-push-notifications

I want to set up push notification for a website. I just followed as described in documentation, but *unfortunately* it is now working.

Here are my settings:

```
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS = {
    "WP_PRIVATE_KEY": BASE_DIR / 'private_key.perm',
    "WP_CLAIMS": {'sub': "mailto: development@example.com"}
}
```

And here is my client-side code. I just copy this code from documentation.

```
.....
<h1>Push Notification Example</h1>
<script>
...............
...........

  var applicationServerKey = "....";
  // In your ready listener
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The service worker has to store in the root of the app
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874068/navigator-serviceworker-is-never-ready
    var browser = loadVersionBrowser('chrome');
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('navigatorPush.service.js?version=1.0.0').then(function (reg) {
      reg.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(applicationServerKey)
      }).then(function (sub) {
        var endpointParts = sub.endpoint.split('/');
        var registration_id = endpointParts[endpointParts.length - 1];
        var data = {
          'browser': browser.name.toUpperCase(),
          'p256dh': btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(sub.getKey('p256dh')))),
          'auth': btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(sub.getKey('auth')))),
          'name': 'XXXXX',
          'registration_id': registration_id
        };
        console.log(data);
      })
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(':^(', err);
    });
  }
```

And here are the error snippets.

[image: Screenshot from 2022-07-17 13-42-11]

What am I missing?

Comment: (Opening `sandeepkush.herokuapp.com` results in: *"Application error. An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command. heroku logs --tail"*).

Comment: What is up with that?